# How to find angle inside a right isosceles triangle with one side and an angle given

Tags: algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry

The problem is as follows:

The picture from below shows a triangle. The conditions are stated in the diagram.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&30^{\circ}\\
2.&15^{\circ}\\
3.&25^{\circ}\\
4.&18^{\circ}\\
\end{array}$

I'm not sure exactly what to do with this problem. So far the only thing which I could spot on was that the right triangle is $45-45-90$ but other than that I'm stuck. Can somebody guide me in the right direction with this problem?.

Comment: Do you know that The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted"?  Please visit  https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @RobertZ Yes I was aware of this. I'm still awaiting for the response of one of the answerers so I can better judge which version does suit my intended approach for this question.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Let ∠DAC = ∠DCB = $x$ and ∠DCA = ∠DAB = $y$. Then, $x+y = 45$ due to the isosceles right triangle ABC and ∠ADC = 180 - ($x+y$) = 135. Apply the sine rule to the triangle ADC,

$$\frac{\sin x}{\sin ∠ADC} = \frac{DC}{AC} = \frac1{\sqrt2}$$

which leads to $\sin x = \frac1{\sqrt2}\cdot \sin 135 = \frac 12$. Thus, ∠DCB = $x$ = 30.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using only synthetic geometry. The following figure is the "solution by picture":

[image: Constellation of regular polygons, squares and equilateral triangles, dan_fulea, mathematics stackexchange, 3507599]

$D$ is on the two emphasized circles, $\Delta XCD$ is equilateral, so  $\widehat{DCB}=30^\circ$.

$\square$

---

**Details:** (If really needed.) Let $X$, be the fourth point of the square with vertices $A,B,C$.

- The given conditions conditions describe an isosceles triangle $\Delta ABC$ with a right angle in $B$,
- and the point $\color{brown}D$ is at the *intersection*

  - of the circle $(C)$ centered in $C$ through $B$ (and $X$), since $CB=CD$,
  - with the circle $(X)$ centered in $X$ through $A,C$. This is because $\widehat{DAC}=\widehat{BCD}$ implies $$
    \begin{aligned}
    \widehat{ADC}&=180^\circ-\widehat{DAC}-\widehat{DAC}
    \\&=180^\circ-\widehat{BCD}-\widehat{DAC}   
    \\&=180^\circ-\widehat{BCA}   
    \\&=180^\circ-45^\circ=135^\circ\ .
    \end{aligned}$$ (A point on the (small) arc $\overset \frown{AC}$ of the circle $(X)$ has the property that $\widehat{ADC}$ has *half* of the measure of the (big) arc arc $\overset \frown{CA}$, with measure $360^\circ-\widehat{AXC} =
    360^\circ-90^\circ=270^\circ$. So it measures $135^\circ$.)

Because of $CD=DX=XC$, the triangle $\Delta CDX$ is equilateral, we obtain an angle of $60^\circ$ in $C$, so 
$$
\widehat{DCB}=
\widehat{XCB}-
\widehat{XCD}=
 90^\circ-60^\circ=30^\circ\ .
$$

$\square$

---

*Bonus:* 
Let us also draw the other quarter circles centered in the other vertices of the square $ABCX$, each having radius $AB=BC=CX=XA$. By the symmetry of the picture, we obtain as in the picture intersections $D,E,F,G$, which are forming a square. 
With the arguments above,

- $ABCX$, $DEFG$ are squares,
- and the triangles
  $\Delta CDX$,
  $\Delta XEA$,
  $\Delta AFB$,
  $\Delta BGC$;
  $\Delta AGD$,
  $\Delta BDE$,
  $\Delta CEF$,
  $\Delta XFG$ are equilateral.

---

*Later EDIT*:

A simplified picture was added:

[image: Equilateral triangle inside a square, dan_fulea, mathematics stackexchange, 3507599]

(This picture is suited for a straightforward proof for the posted problem, but it hides the symmetry in the picture. Note that many such problems arise as particular, partial pictures in a constellation involving a regular polygon. Finding it is a good way to understand the special situation, and to be able to react in similar situations. Or to even compose problems.)

Comment: Your drawing it is a little bit complicated for me to understand. Perhaps does it exist an easier version?. I'm confused because of the many lines crossing in the interior of the circle.